# error[im006][microsoft][odbc driver manager] driver's SQLsetconectionattr failed

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I'm getting below error: it works fine on one of my dev servers and but on remote prod server it fails

```
 string msAccessConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + fileName;

        try
        {
            using (OdbcConnection sourceConnection = new OdbcConnection(msAccessConnectionString))
            using (sqlConnection)
            {
                sourceConnection.Open();

                 // code to update the table or retrieve the table

             } 
           }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("ERROR --- ERROR --- ERROR --- ERROR --- ERROR ---");
            sb.AppendLine(ex.Message.ToString());

        }
```

Comment: what is the error message ? does your remote server have access driver installed?

Comment: error[im006][microsoft][odbc driver manager] driver's SQLsetconectionattr failed
 is the error message. it has access driver installed as well.